# columns of the table are not visible completly

Tags: html, css

we created table in magento site , but some part of the table is not visible.

in the below image, last column is not visible completely.

we are using following code :

```
.wk_content th {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.wk_check_first_td{
    border-left: none!important;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}


.wk_first_td{
    width: 26%;
    border-left: none!important;
```

[image]

Comment: Set width auto in your wk_first_td, and show the result.

Comment: Do you want it to fit or do you want to make it scrollable?

Comment: @fsn still same result.

Comment: @user3821538 i want this scrollable, its already there. but problem is column is not visible fully

Comment: .wk_content {
    overflow: auto;
}

Comment: @user3821538 still its not working

Comment: even if you have set total column width less than 100% if the single non-breakable elements(such as button, textbox) exceed the column width the column rezises to accommodate such elements and the table width exceeds  100%

Comment: you can see the difference here https://jsfiddle.net/ev32yks5/

Comment: @BabyinCoding I sincerely hope you don't use those credentials on any other sites.

Comment: @RRR what i can do for solution ?

Comment: @JosephMarikle its a demo site and i am not using those credentials in any other site.

Comment: @BabyinCoding Add a size for your input boxes as `input {width:90%;}` which makes it fit to 90% of the `<td>` width. Check out the same [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ev32yks5/1/)

Comment: @BabyinCoding resize textbox width

Comment: thanks a lot for all.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace below css

```
.ama1 {
     border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
     border-radius: 5px;
     padding: 10px;
     position: relative;
     top: 10px;
     width: 70px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: i checked it and it's work perfectly ...can i share photo here..?

Comment: is this file path : skin/frontend/default/em0113/marketplace/css/style.css

Comment: i understand ...width: 70px !important;    just add important in width

Comment: add `!important` to width  the css is written in your page

Comment: i added like `width: 70px;!important;` but not working for me

Comment: add like this  :    width: 70px !important;

Comment: @DhavalPatel at the end , 2 parallel lines are displaying, pease help me to remove one.

Comment: @RRR at the end , 2 parallel lines are displaying, pease help me to remove one.

Comment: please open myproductslist.phtml file where you add  .ama1 
{
width: 80px; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;  padding: 10px; position : relative; top: 10px;"
}   this css. please remove from phtml file.Please check page source view

Comment: pls check the link now, i removed from code in phtml file

Comment: @DhavalPatel now its hiding last 3 columns, may i add code in phtml file again ?

Comment: please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545936/display-background-color-for-the-page-align-texts-at-center